# Создание пустой DLL минимального размера

Tags: dll

Где взять или на чем написать пустую бибилиотеку? Необходимо только наличие версии, которое будет меняться через reshack.
Мониторинг отслеживает версию dll.
Содержимое должно быть пустое.
Размер приближенный к 1 кб.

Answer (score 3):

Создайте проект C++ DLL в Visual Studio.

1. Переключитесь в Release.
2. Отключите отладку (.pdb): *Properties > Linker > Debugger > Generate Debug Info > No*.
3. Отключите включение манифеста (.manifest): *Properties > Manifest Tool > Input and Output > Embed Manifest > No*.
4. Отключите подключение всех библиотек (Ignore all default libraries): *Properties > Linker > Input > Ignore all default libraries > Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB)*.
5. Отключите точку входа (No entry point): *Properties > Linker > Advanced > No Entry Point > Yes (/NOENTRY)*.
6. Отключите проверки буфера (Buffer Security Checks): *Properties > C/C++ > Security Check > Disable Security Check (/GS-)*.

Имеем DLL в 512 байт.

Теперь добавьте ресурс с версией (*Resource Files > Add > Resource > Version*). Имеем DLL в 2048 байт.

Ещё можно поиграться с выравниванием секций (*Properties > Linker > Advanced > Section Alignment > 16*), но до 1024 байт опуститься не получается. Можно попробовать минималистичные упаковщики типа FSG (учтите только, что антивирусы его не любят).

Держите собранную библиотеку: http://www.mediafire.com/download/cjmasqalprdo9me/TinyLibVersion.dll